# Python/Pandas - Select rows that match more than one condition on group

Tags: python, pandas

Given the sample data:

```
data = [['john', 'test_1', pd.NA], ['john', 'test_2', 'fail'], ['john', 'test_3', 'fail'],
    ['mary', 'test_1', pd.NA], ['mary', 'test_2', 'fail'], ['mary', 'test_3', pd.NA],
    ['nick', 'test_1', pd.NA],
    ['liam', 'test_1', pd.NA], ['liam', 'test_2', pd.NA],
    ['jane', 'test_1', pd.NA], ['jane', 'test_2', 'pass'], ['jane', 'test_3', pd.NA],
    ['emma', 'test_1', pd.NA], ['emma', 'test_2', pd.NA], ['emma', 'test_3', 'fail']]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['name', 'test', 'result'])
```

I'm having trouble trying to select the people that didn't failed test_2.

[image]

```
df = df.groupby('name').filter(lambda x : ((x.result != 'fail')).all())
```

The code above partially works by removing john and mary, the problem is that also removes emma because the condition doesn't apply to test_2 only.

The following code also does not work for my desired output:

```
df = df.groupby('name').filter(lambda x : ((x.test == 'test_2') & (x.result != 'fail')).all())
```

I'm sure my issue is more logic related, but I've have spent some hours trying to figure it out without success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Determine who failed the test with [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and drop them with another boolean indexing and [`isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
# identify which names failed "test_2"
drop = df.loc[df['test'].eq('test_2') & df['result'].eq('fail'), 'name'].unique()
# ['john', 'mary']

# select the other names
out = df[~df['name'].isin(drop)]
```

You code was incorrect since you were filtering for the users that took the "test_2" but didn't fail **for all rows in the group**

The correct code with filter would have been:

```
# do NOT keep users that ever passed "test_2" AND failed
out = (df.groupby('name')
         .filter(lambda x : not ( (x.test == 'test_2')
                                 &(x.result == 'fail')
                                ).any())
     )
```

Or using [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws):

```
# keep users that always passed something other than "test_2" OR didn't fail
# (equivalent to: never passed "test_2" AND failed)
out = (df.groupby('name')
         .filter(lambda x : (  (x.test != 'test_2')
                             | (x.result != 'fail')
                            ).all())
      )
```

Output:

```
    name    test result
6   nick  test_1   <NA>
7   liam  test_1   <NA>
8   liam  test_2   <NA>
9   jane  test_1   <NA>
10  jane  test_2   pass
11  jane  test_3   <NA>
12  emma  test_1   <NA>
13  emma  test_2   <NA>
14  emma  test_3   fail
```

Comment: Thanks mozway, that's exactly what I was looking for. I'm marking this answer as accepted because it's closer to what I was thinking.  Also thanks to Panda Kim and gtomer for providing different solutions. It's always good to learn new ways to solve the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
# creates a dataframe of failed in test_2
test2 = df[(df['test'] == 'test_2') & (df['result'] == 'fail')]
# create a list of their names
names = test2['name'].to_list()
# filter them out
df[~df['name'].isin(names)]

    name    test result
6   nick  test_1   <NA>
7   liam  test_1   <NA>
8   liam  test_2   <NA>
9   jane  test_1   <NA>
10  jane  test_2   pass
11  jane  test_3   <NA>
12  emma  test_1   <NA>
13  emma  test_2   <NA>
14  emma  test_3   fail
```

Comment: This is not was OP asked, this select the incorrect names. The boolean shouldn't be `!= 'fail'`

Comment: Yes, it's correct now (same logic as mine) ;)

Comment: @mozway - cannot compete with your speed :-)\

Comment: Actually OP's issue was not so much with the principle, but failing to set up the correct boolean conditions ;)

Answer (score 1):

use groupby + transform

```
cond = df['test'].eq('test_2') & df['result'].eq('fail')
out = df[~cond.groupby(df['name']).transform(any)]
```

out:

```
    name    test result
6   nick  test_1   <NA>
7   liam  test_1   <NA>
8   liam  test_2   <NA>
9   jane  test_1   <NA>
10  jane  test_2   pass
11  jane  test_3   <NA>
12  emma  test_1   <NA>
13  emma  test_2   <NA>
14  emma  test_3   fail
```